# How do I build and use my own VHDL library?

Tags: vhdl, library, vivado, activehdl, aldec

I am trying to create a components library in VHDL. I have many .vhd source files with different components. Ideally I would like to be able to instantiate them in a design using the same method as a standard library.(or similar)

*example:*

```
library my_lib;
use my_lib.something.all;
```

And build a design using these components structurally.
Ideally I'd like to keep these as separate files because there are attached custom symbol (bds) files associated.

The symbols only matter when using Active-HDL (10.1) Being able to pull these files in and use them in the block diagram file would be great!

I would be using Aldec Active-HDL(10.1), Xilinx Vivado(2014.2), and Altera Quartus (9.1 web).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[Xilinx Vivado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011795/add-library-to-vivado-2014-4):

> You can create/change the library a file resides in Vivado by clicking on the file, then clicking the button to the right of the Library label in the `Source File Properties` tab. You can create a library by assigning a file to a library that doesn't exist.

[Altera Quartus II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580207/compiling-vhdl-into-a-library-using-altera-quartus-ii):

> You can specify the library under `Properties`, for example:
>   [image]
>   You can also modify the Quartus II settings (".qsf") file for the project using `set_global_assignment` options.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your component declarations into a VHDL package. This package is then loaded by a `use` statement.

A library can not be created by a file, but all tools - that I know of - have the ability to create a library in the project and assign files to them. Or some tools have a file property field to assign the selected file to a library.

If your intention is to spare component declarations in the architecture header, there is also a 'new' syntax to specify the full name of an entity:

```
myinst : entity mylib.myentity
  port map (
  ...
  );
```

You just need to name the used library like the well known IEEE:

```
library mylib;
```